# Minimize and Float Player on Scroll not working correctly for JW Player

Tags: javascript, html5-video, jwplayer

I just set up JW Player instance on a WordPress page. I wanted to re-create the functionality found here at https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/advanced/minimize-and-float-video-on-scroll/ where the player moves to  the left or right side of the page and scrolls with the user. I have entered in the code given from JW Player as follows:

```
    <div id="float-video-player" class="player-container"></div>

     <!-------------------------- JW Player Float and scroll ----------------------------->

<script type="text/javascript">

// initialize jwplayer
var playerInstance = jwplayer('float-video-player');

// player dom elements
var playerContainerEl = document.querySelector('.player-container');

// returns video player position from top of document
  function getElementOffsetTop(el) {
    var boundingClientRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var bodyEl = document.body;
    var docEl = document.documentElement;
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || bodyEl.scrollTop;
    var clientTop = docEl.clientTop || bodyEl.clientTop || 0;
    return Math.round(boundingClientRect.top + scrollTop - clientTop);
}

// returns the current y scroll position
function getScrollTop() {
    var docEl = document.documentElement;
    return (window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop) - (docEl.clientTop || 0);
}

// configure jwplayer instance
playerInstance.setup({
    autostart: true,
    file: 'https://cdn.jwplayer.com/players/jgjfjfj',
    primary: 'html5',
    setFullscreen: true,
    width: '100%'
});

// when jwplayer instance is ready
playerInstance.on('ready', function() {
    var config = playerInstance.getConfig();
    var utils = playerInstance.utils;
    // get height of player element
    var playerHeight = config.containerHeight;

    // get player element position from top of document
    var playerOffsetTop = getElementOffsetTop(playerContainerEl);

    // set player container to match height of actual video element
    // this prevents container from disappearing and changing element positions
    // on page when player becomes minimized. this also leaves a nice visual
    // placeholder space for minimized player to return to when appropriate
    playerContainerEl.style.height = playerHeight + 'px';

    // below we handle window scroll event without killing performance
    // this is a minimal approach. please consider implementing something more extensive:
    // i.e. http://joji.me/en-us/blog/how-to-develop-high-performance-onscroll-event

    // determine player display when scroll event is called
    // if inline player is no longer visible in viewport, add class
    // .player-minimize to minimize and float. otherwise, remove the class to put
    // player back to inline inline position
    function onScrollViewHandler() {
        var minimize = getScrollTop() >= playerOffsetTop;

        utils.toggleClass(playerContainerEl, 'player-minimize', minimize);
        // update the player's size so the controls are adjusted
        playerInstance.resize();
    }

    // namespace for whether or not we are waiting for setTimeout() to finish
    var isScrollTimeout = false;

    // window onscroll event handler
    window.onscroll = function() {
        // skip if we're waiting on a scroll update timeout to finish
        if (isScrollTimeout) return;
        // flag that a new timeout will begin
        isScrollTimeout = true;
        // otherwise, call scroll event view handler
        onScrollViewHandler();
        // set new timeout
        setTimeout(function() {
            // reset timeout flag to false (no longer waiting)
            isScrollTimeout = false;
        }, 80);

    };

});
</script>
```

So when I push the code to the site, the player is there, but the intended functionality doesn't work, is there something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <style type="text/css">
        .demo-layout-content {
           margin-right: 250px;
           margin-left: 250px;
    }
        .player-container {
            background-color: black;
            float: left;
            margin: 20px 20px 10px 0;
            width: 500px;
        }

        .player-minimize .player-position {
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 2px;
            bottom: 20px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            left: 20px;
            padding: 7px;
            position: fixed;
            width: 300px;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .demo-single .demo-layout-content .jwplayer {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .demo-layout-content {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .demo-single .demo-layout-content h2 {
            font-size: 42px;
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .demo-single .demo-layout-content p,
        .demo-single .demo-layout-content p + p {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .demo-single .demo-layout-vertical .demo-layout-code {
            max-width: 900px;
            width: 100%;
        } </style>

        </head>

            <div class="demo-container">

              <div class="demo-layout-vertical">
                <div class="demo-layout-content">
                  <script src="//content.jwplatform.com/libraries/IDzF9Zmk.js"></script>

        <div class="player-container">
            <div class="player-position">
                <div id="player"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dui ex, suscipit eu ultrices et, congue nec quam. Sed ultricies bibendum quam at sollicitudin. Mauris ut dapibus sapien. Sed turpis mauris, cursus in enim ut, sodales tempus tortor. Donec varius aliquam massa. Donec fermentum pellentesque molestie. Integer varius porta vehicula. Etiam volutpat nibh et nisl malesuada, vel auctor tellus commodo. Aliquam quis pharetra diam. Aliquam efficitur molestie viverra. Curabitur eu vulputate odio. Praesent sollicitudin tincidunt rhoncus. Phasellus nunc metus, blandit quis arcu at, feugiat viverra lorem. Phasellus sollicitudin augue at tincidunt ullamcorper. Quisque non ipsum augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dui ex, suscipit eu ultrices et, congue nec quam. Sed ultricies bibendum quam at sollicitudin. Mauris ut dapibus sapien. Sed turpis mauris, cursus in enim ut, sodales tempus tortor. Donec varius aliquam massa. Donec fermentum pellentesque molestie. Integer varius porta vehicula. Etiam volutpat nibh et nisl malesuada, vel auctor tellus commodo. Aliquam quis pharetra diam. Aliquam efficitur molestie viverra. Curabitur eu vulputate odio. Praesent sollicitudin tincidunt rhoncus. Phasellus nunc metus, blandit quis arcu at, feugiat viverra lorem. Phasellus sollicitudin augue at tincidunt ullamcorper. Quisque non ipsum augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dui ex, suscipit eu ultrices et, congue nec quam. Sed ultricies bibendum quam at sollicitudin. Mauris ut dapibus sapien. Sed turpis mauris, cursus in enim ut, sodales tempus tortor. Donec varius aliquam massa. Donec fermentum pellentesque molestie. Integer varius porta vehicula. Etiam volutpat nibh et nisl malesuada, vel auctor tellus commodo. Aliquam quis pharetra diam. Aliquam efficitur molestie viverra. Curabitur eu vulputate odio. Praesent sollicitudin tincidunt rhoncus. Phasellus nunc metus, blandit quis arcu at, feugiat viverra lorem. Phasellus sollicitudin augue at tincidunt ullamcorper. Quisque non ipsum augue.</p>

        <p>Donec eget urna sit amet tellus varius efficitur ac sodales lorem. Nullam id elit eros. Etiam finibus nunc vel ante condimentum, eu ullamcorper lorem commodo. Maecenas pretium, nulla id iaculis convallis, lectus dui feugiat arcu, sit amet placerat augue turpis quis ante. Sed sit amet ornare dui. Ut maximus suscipit dictum. Fusce vitae justo tortor. Cras ac vestibulum augue, sed tristique felis. Nam tincidunt sapien velit, dignissim tempus justo laoreet in.</p>

        <p>Vivamus eleifend congue lectus, quis ullamcorper tortor accumsan non. Duis vitae mattis tortor. Nulla vitae odio enim. Praesent eu orci at elit venenatis luctus. Praesent at luctus mauris. Maecenas accumsan posuere varius. Suspendisse id vehicula mauris. Vestibulum id neque vitae dui lobortis eleifend non sed erat. Nunc posuere augue nec turpis ornare facilisis. Vivamus lectus justo, commodo sed molestie consequat, dictum sed est. Maecenas semper velit placerat ex finibus rhoncus. Duis nisi justo, pharetra ac ipsum ac, gravida venenatis risus. Praesent eu est ultrices, lobortis felis quis, volutpat augue. Mauris non varius lacus. Etiam pulvinar ornare lectus et tristique.</p></div></div></div>


        <script type="text/javascript">// initialize jwplayer
        var playerInstance = jwplayer('player');
        // player dom elements
        var playerContainerEl = document.querySelector('.player-container');
        // returns video player position from top of document
        function getElementOffsetTop(el) {
          var boundingClientRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
          var bodyEl = document.body;
          var docEl = document.documentElement;
          var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || bodyEl.scrollTop;
          var clientTop = docEl.clientTop || bodyEl.clientTop || 0;
          return Math.round(boundingClientRect.top + scrollTop - clientTop);
        }
        // returns the current y scroll position
        function getScrollTop() {
          var docEl = document.documentElement;
          return (window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop) - (docEl.clientTop || 0);
        }
        // configure jwplayer instance
        playerInstance.setup({
          "autostart": "true",
          "file": "//content.jwplatform.com/manifests/vM7nH0Kl.m3u8",
          "width": "100%"});

        // when jwplayer instance is ready
        playerInstance.on('ready', function() {
                var config = playerInstance.getConfig();
                var utils = playerInstance.utils;
                // get height of player element
                var playerHeight = config.containerHeight;
                // get player element position from top of document
                var playerOffsetTop = getElementOffsetTop(playerContainerEl);
                // set player container to match height of actual video element
                // this prevents container from disappearing and changing element positions
                // on page when player becomes minimized. this also leaves a nice visual
                // placeholder space for minimized player to return to when appropriate
                playerContainerEl.style.height = playerHeight + 'px';
                // below we handle window scroll event without killing performance
                // this is a minimal approach. please consider implementing something more extensive:
                // i.e. http://joji.me/en-us/blog/how-to-develop-high-performance-onscroll-event
                // determine player display when scroll event is called
                // if inline player is no longer visible in viewport, add class
                // .player-minimize to minimize and float. otherwise, remove the class to put
                // player back to inline inline position
                function onScrollViewHandler() {
                    var minimize = getScrollTop() >= playerOffsetTop;
                    utils.toggleClass(playerContainerEl, 'player-minimize', minimize);
                    // update the player's size so the controls are adjusted
                    playerInstance.resize();
                }
                // namespace for whether or not we are waiting for setTimeout() to finish
                var isScrollTimeout = false;
                // window onscroll event handler
                window.onscroll = function() {
                    // skip if we're waiting on a scroll update timeout to finish
                    if (isScrollTimeout) return;
                    // flag that a new timeout will begin
                    isScrollTimeout = true;
                    // otherwise, call scroll event view handler
                    onScrollViewHandler();
                    // set new timeout
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // reset timeout flag to false (no longer waiting)
                        isScrollTimeout = false;
                    }, 80);
                };
            });</script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          function setVersion() {
            if (typeof jwplayer === 'undefined') {
              setTimeout(setVersion, 100);
              return;
            }
            if (jwplayer && jwplayer().id) {
              jwplayer().on('ready', function() {
                document.getElementById('demo-player-version').innerHTML = jwplayer.version.split('+')[0];
              });
            }
          }
          setVersion();</script>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The code on the JW Player demo requires you use additional CSS, which are included in JozeAE's answer.

For example:
`utils.toggleClass(playerContainerEl, 'player-minimize', minimize);`

This requires that you have a class, `player-minimize`, which defines the minimized state.

Per the answer above (taken from the JW Player demo page), that would be `player-minimize` and `player-container` (which is a DIV wrapping the player):

```
        .player-container {
            background-color: black;
            float: left;
            margin: 20px 20px 10px 0;
            width: 500px;
        }

        .player-minimize .player-position {
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 2px;
            bottom: 20px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            left: 20px;
            padding: 7px;
            position: fixed;
            width: 300px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
```

The styles can be adjusted to fit your needs, though.

Comment: Thanks. JW Player actually built this feature into their new player, so I don't have to go through the pain anymore